# How can I create a dynamic ListView columns for MySQL searches?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a single ListView that is used for many different types of MySQL searches which all return different data. 
Take the following query for example.

```
  "SELECT `entry`, `name` FROM `accounts` WHERE `name` LIKE %@name%";
```

Each time I run a query I have to setup ListView columns so it will display properly.

```
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.Columns.Add("Entry", 50, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Name", 210, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
```

Is it possible to add ListView columns based upon the column data that is returned from the MySQL server rather than the above code?

Comment: You mean you need to add coulmns dynamically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fill data from database and than based on data you can add columns to listview like this.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString()))
 {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT `entry`, `name` FROM `accounts` WHERE `name` LIKE %@name%", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "somename");
    SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    dAdapter.Fill(dt);
 }
foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
 {
    listView1.Columns.Add(dc.ColumnName, 50, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you might want to try something like this:

```
string clmHeader = null;
int clmWidth = 0;

foreach (string s in List<T>())
{
    clmHeader = s;
    //Add an invisible label to your form
    lbl.Text = s;
    clmWidth = lbl.Width;

    ListView.Columns.Add(clmHeader, clmWidth, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
}
```